# ImportError: cannot import name 'input_reader_pb2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, protoc

working on win10 64-bit

when i trying to train my model by `E:\projectx\model-master\models-master>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config`

this error appear

> File "train.py", line 49, in 
>           from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
>         File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py",
>   line 27, in 
>           from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
>         File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py",
>   line 27, in 
>           from object_detection.protos import input_reader_pb2
>           ImportError: cannot import name 'input_reader_pb2'

i do run protoc 3.4 `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`
but the error still exist 
i check all thing and it is should be fine and work, it is going me mad!!

please help....
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you already compiled all **.proto** files in *object_detection/protos/* . You should see python files which have '**_pb2**' like **eval_pb2**. If you can see these then go to *models/research* directory and run these code one by one:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

From inside the `object_detection` folder:

```
protoc ../object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

This command will generate a `*_pb2.py` for each `.proto` file in the `object_detection/protos/` folder.

---

Note: Is important to specify a path above `object_detection`, otherwise errors would occur, most likely:

> object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
>
> protos/anchor_generator.proto:8:1: Import "object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
>
> protos/anchor_generator.proto:17:5: "FlexibleGridAnchorGenerator" is not defined.

---

If the error persists probably you are in the wrong folder, take a look at the output message to see from where it is trying to import the file and execute the command in the right directory.

**As last resort**: Download the `object_detection` module from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research
place it in your working directory, enter it and re-execute the command above.
It will surely works as local modules have import priority over `sys.path`.

If not, the error message would be probably different from the one reported and the problem lies on the *tensorflow* installation or the *protobuf compiler*; as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457729/8411453) where the problem was caused by the *protoc* version.

other useful links: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5264

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't added module slim to PYTHONPATH.It can be done by running below code inside models/research directory.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems that you didnt compile protobuf.
For solving it:

1. Download the latest protoc exe here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases (in your case should be win32)
2. Rename that folder to "protoc"
3. Put that folder inside models/research
4. in models/research via console, launch:

   ```
   protoc/bin/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
   ```

I dont know exactly if that command will work on windows, but you have to be sure that you are using the protoc compiler that you downloaded (v.3.6) instead of the protoc in your enviroment.

Comment: this command doesn't work on windows and even if you compile files one by one with batch files, you still will be getting the error