# Import Error: Cannot Import name input_reader_pb2

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, training-data

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API to train my object detection model. I accumulated the dataset, and am going through the [this](https://becominghuman.ai/tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial-training-and-evaluating-custom-object-detector-ed2594afcf73) tutorial.

Everything went fine until I tried to train my dataset. When I run the following line on terminal,

```
python train.py --logtostderr \ 
   --train_dir=training/ \       
--pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "legacy/train.py", line 49, in <module>
from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1- 
py2.7.egg/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 27, in 
<module>
from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1- 
py2.7.egg/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 
24, in <module>
from object_detection.protos import input_reader_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name input_reader_pb2
```

I tried searching through sites and comments, but unfortunately couldn't get around, could anyone please help out!

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I was using protoc version 3.0.0(protobuf compiler) which is in beta testing mode and has some bugs. So the first check for protobuf version using

```
proto --version
```

if it libprotoc 3.0.0, purge it and install 2.6.1
once done that,

```
cd models/research
protoc object_detection/ --python.out=.
```

now it should work!

Comment: Unknown flag: --python.out

Answer (score 0):

To solve the 'Unknown flag' error reported in comment
use `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`
The previous answer misspelled with '. ' in python'.'out

Comment: Gonna need an explanation to your answer as to what your command does and why it is necessary.